# How to give one time only camera access to Skype app

Tags: macos, permission, camera, skype

I want that everytime a videocall starts on skype, MacOS asks for my permission to give access to Skype. I don't want to give permanent camera access to Skype.

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: Why do you want this? Do you fear that Skype will use the camera when you are not on a call?

Comment: This might make a general question. I’m curious - is this about privacy and that you don’t trust some apps like Skype or Zoom to have open access to the camera or is this more a stability issue - you see crashes when you do this so you minimize that permission?

Comment: Just put a sticker over the camera :-) If you are concerned about privacy, removing microphone access might be even more important

Comment: I had an incident where I unknowingly accepted a video call from a female colleague (pressing enter accepts a video call apparently) and I was half naked at that time. So it was an embarrassing incident. That is why I wanted an additional check for each video call.
Right now I have placed a sticker over the camera.

Answer (score 1):

You can just give it access for that one call and then revoke its access after.

To change the camera permissions on a specific app who has requested for it:

Settings > Security & Privacy > Camera Tab and then click the check mark next to the app you want to change permissions to.

You may have to click the lock icon on the bottom left corner to change these settings.

Comment: But I would have to do that everytime and it is easy to forget to remove access.

Comment: @Sahil Only way I know of without third party apps